# Embed a Microsoft RichEdit 8 control in a Mathematica notebook using .NETLink?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, formatting, .netlink

Does anyone know whether or not it's possible to embed a RichEdit 8 control within a Mathematica Notebook using .NETLink?

The goal here would be able to both view and edit mathematical text typeset using Microsoft Word 2013 from within a Mathematica notebook.

More background on the development of mathematical typesetting capabilities in Microsoft Office (and the RichEdit control) is available here:  [Murray Sargent's blog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/murrays/).

Comment: +1 and FWIW, I'd be interested in being able to embed *ANY* type of external content, especially some type of video/audio player that one could control within MMA (without having to import the data, etc). When v8 introduced the webcam features, I figured out a way (via 3rd party prog) to push video to the webcam so it would then show up in MMA. Wish I knew more .NET so I could ask the right questions to help move things along...

Comment: I agree ... it would be nice to see the notebook evolve into a "container" that can hold different media types which perhaps one day could be manipulated using the Mathematica programming language.  I'd even settle at the moment for being able to render MathJax content within a notebook frame using an embedded browser component via .NETLink.  Ultimately, I hope that the native math typesetting in Mathematica will reach a higher level of sophistication and polish which rivals what LaTeX and Office 2013 are capable of producing.